# Set of hyperplanes to polyhedron topology

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, polygons, polyhedra

## Problem

By intersection of a set of planes (in three-dimensional space) I constructed an edge-vertex topology structure ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh4zc.png)).

I was able to reconstruct the polygons in this structure by `minimum_cycle_basis` for each plane (I believe also sometimes called `face-cycles`). And create a polygon adjacency structure.

The next step would be to reconstruct polyhedra from these polygons. However, I would not know how to.

## Attempt

I tried to analyse all cycles in the polygon topology, however many may belong to one of the two polyhedra for each polygon and many do not.

I do know (because all geometry is result of plane intersection) that all polygons and all polyhedra are convex.

## Question

How to efficiently find all polyhedra?